# C++ method returns 0

Tags: c++, methods, division

I have this method that returns 0, and i don't know why.

Method:

```
double Fraccion::getDivision()
{
    double d;
    d = numerador/denominador;
    cout << fixed << numerador << "/" << denominador << "=" << d << endl;
    return d;
}
```

This is the output console:

```
Introduce el numerador //This is in the main file
5
Introduce el denominador //This is in the main file
25
5/25=0.000000
Division: 0.000000
```

Comment: Are `numerador` and `denominador` ints?

Comment: It's not enough for `d` to be a `double` in order to get correct result, one of `numerador` and `denominador` should be a `double`.

Comment: Use `d = 1.0*numerador/denominador;` or `d = ((double)numerador)/denominador;`

Comment: As you know, the problem is integer truncation.  The solution is to modify your expression so the division uses floating point instead of integer. Here's a nice article: [C Programming: mixing double, float and int](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/articles/11239.aspx)

Comment: Thank you R Sahu with the casting `(double)` works :) I'm new in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given output, it seems that `numerador` and `denominador` are `int`s. Therefore, dividing them will be done in [integer division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29#Of_integers) (i.e., taking only the whole part), and only then be promoted to a `double`. You can avoid this by explicitly casting before diving:

```
d = ((double) numerador)/denominador;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `numerador` and `denominador` are integral types, `numerador/denomindor` has an integral type as well. With integer division, `5/25` is `0`. This result is then converted to the `double` `0.0`. If you want floating-point division, you need to convert the operands either with an explicit cast, or using the implicit conversions that apply. For example,

```
d = 1.0*numerador / denominador;
```